# Recursion to loop using a stack

Tags: c++, loops, recursion, stack

I want to convert the following program into a non-recursive code using a stack and a loop:

```
void write(int n) {
    if (n>0) {
        write(n-1);
        cout << n << " ";
        write(n-1);
    }
}
```

And here is the code I am using but that currently does not work, and I do not know why:

```
stack<int> S;
S.push(n);
while (not S.empty()) {
    int k = S.top(); 
    S.pop()
    if (k>0) {
        S.push(k-1);
        cout<<k<<" ";
        S.push(k-1);
    }
}
```

It doesn't work and I have no idea how to simulate that recursion. I thought it was enough to push into the stack the equivalent recursive call.

thanks

Comment: Avoid the double `S.push(k-1);`

Comment: I need two push since there are 2 rec. calls on the write function, otherwise it will just write numbers from n to 1.

Comment: @DieterLücking there is double call in recursive so that not the problem

Comment: @Ruben your assumption is wrong, it would be equivalent if there is only one call

Comment: Then how can you make it with one call?

Comment: @Ruben I mean if `write()` would have only one recursive call then one push to the stack would be equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you do 2 pushes to the stack, but first `write()` is called recursively before the print with all call chain.

Here is iterative equivalent for your recursive calls:

```
std::stack<int> S;
for( int i = n; i > 0; --i )
   S.push( i );

while( not S.empty() ) {
    int k = S.top();
    S.pop();
    for( int i = k - 1; i > 0; --i ) {
        S.push( i );
    }
    std::cout << k << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the first call to `write(n - 1)` happens before the output, but the evaluation of the popped value happens after it.

You can make your stack simulate actual activation records:

```
enum Action
{
  Call, Write
};

struct Record
{
  Action action;
  int arg;
};

stack<Record> S;
S.push({Call, n});
while (not S.empty()) {
  auto rec = S.top();
  S.pop()
  switch (rec.action) {
    case Call:
      if (rec.arg > 0) {
        S.push({Call, rec.arg - 1}); // corresponds to 2nd write() call
        S.push({Write, rec.arg});
        S.push({Call, rec.arg - 1}); // corresponds to 1st write() call
      }
      break;
    case Write:
      std::cout << rec.arg << ' ';
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: So you make a distnction between when we have to write and when we have to push? In that case, you are never changing Rec.arg ?

Comment: @Ruben Why should I change it? It's just a value read from the stack. It would be like changing the value of `n` in your original recursive function.

Comment: nvm, just realised of the way you push :p

Comment: So there is a variable that indicates what is needed to do. Provided there were more situations, let's say 3, would this variable have 3 values instead? And ofc the switch would change accordingly?

Comment: @Ruben Yes, it would.

Comment: Alright so this is a general, recursive to iterative strategy, I am loving it!